# glCompileShader segfault because of an if statement

Tags: c, opengl, segmentation-fault, glsl, shader

This fragment shader compiles and works without a problem:

```
#version 330 core
uniform sampler2D sampler;
uniform vec3 clr;
vec2 pos;
void main(void) {
    pos.x = gl_FragCoord.x / 960.0;
    pos.y = gl_FragCoord.y / 540.0;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(clr,1) * texture(sampler, pos.st);
}
```

This throws segmentation fault somewhere inside `glCompileShader`:

```
#version 330 core
uniform sampler2D sampler;
uniform vec3 clr;
vec2 pos;
void main(void) {
    pos.x = gl_FragCoord.x / 960.0;
    pos.y = gl_FragCoord.y / 540.0;
    if (texture(sampler, pos.st).r > 0.5) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(clr, 1) * 0.5;
    }
    else {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(clr, 1);
    }
}
```

Everything else is identical. Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.

Comment: glCompileShader shouldn't segfault because of invalid code; There is either an issue with your driver or with your code that creates and compiles the shader.

Comment: Are you sure you have the opengl context when you try to compile the shader ? Try to check the return value of glGetString(GL_VERSION) to check whether you have the context or not

Answer (score 1):

> This throws segmentation fault somewhere inside glCompileShader

Problems like these are usually caused by out-of-bounds memory access. The API of glShaderSource is specified (version 4.5) as following (emphasis by me):

> The command
>
> ```
> void glShaderSource(
>     GLuint shader,
>     GLsizei count,
>     const GLchar *const *string,
>     const GLint *length );
> ```
>
> loads source code into the shader object named shader. string is an
>   array of count pointers to **optionally null-terminated** character
>   strings that make up the source code. The **length** argument is an array
>   with the **number of chars** in each string (the string length). If an
>   element in length is negative, its accompanying string is
>   null-terminated. If length is NULL, all strings in the string argument
>   are considered null-terminated.

This means that if you don't null-terminate your shader strings OpenGL expects you to pass it length information or vice versa.

Why is this important is your case? The one important difference between your two shader sources is the length of the shader source string. And it's quite possible that after the end of the shorter source a couple of null bytes may appear¹. And the small change of making your shader source string just a little bit longer may have a huge effect on where it's going to end up in memory and what comes after it.

So why might your shader source string not be null-terminated? For example if you read it from a file and allocate the memory to be exactly the file size. In that case there's not going to be a null-termination character.

The takeaway is: Either properly null-terminate your shader source strings or explicitly pass in the shader source string length. Preferably do both (it never hurts to be paranoid about out-of-bounds memory access).

---

1: Maybe leftovers from a previous allocation at the same memory spot, or maybe your source string was short enough that it fit into a single page and the malloc implementation decided that requesting a fresh page would be appropriate (and fresh pages usually read zero unless it's not explicitly requested to not initialize them).

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work fine. The problem in your code is tricky as it might be the problem during  optimisation.

Also, isn't it 'texture2D' instead of 'texture'?

```
#version 330 core
uniform sampler2D sampler;
uniform vec3 clr;
vec2 pos;
void main(void) {
    pos.x = gl_FragCoord.x / 960.0;
    pos.y = gl_FragCoord.y / 540.0;

    float rValue = texture(sampler, pos.st).r;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(clr, 1.0) * mix(1.0, 0.5, rValue > 0.5);
}
```

Comment: It's been just "texture" ever since GLSL-1.20. https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/texture.xhtml

Comment: In a `core` profile, it definitely shouldn't be `texture2D` (if the driver allows this, it's in error). You can use the old `texture2D` stuff if you want if you remove `core` from the shader version directive... but why would you want to? The dimensions of textures are pretty unimportant when figuring out what the purpose of the lookup is and so overloads exist to take care of that stuff; the only time you use a differently named texture function in GLSL 1.30+ is when you are doing something fundamentally different such as shadow mapping, projection, explicit LOD selection, etc.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the info. I am more from a GLSL es background so 'texture2D' is what we use there.